# How to call PHP function when AJAX query success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter-3

I used AJAX in my project. Code below.

```
           $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             data: ...,
             success: function(data) {<?php calc(); ?>},
             error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {
             console.log('Error' + errorMessage);
             }
           });
```

I need to get data on same page without any page reload that is why I don't use url in my AJAX. When AJAX success I want to trigger function named **calc**. The calculation in calc function, based datas which came from ajax also some database queries involving on these calculations that is why I have to use PHP function. But when I try my code calc function doesn't wait for success. Just triggering directly.

What's wrong I couldn't get it. How can I handle with this situation. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do ajax when complete. Means, execute the ajax code in the success function. You are trying to call a php function inside the success code which will not work.You should do another ajax on success. Or put the code you want to get executed in the success function. In place of `<?php calc()?>` put the comple function code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it doesn't work the way you described. You can't mess JS and PHP part just like this.

When you wrote things like `<?php calc(); ?>` it will always be called when page is being generated (on the start) and result will be included as plain text in that exact place where you insert that code.

What you want to do is to fetch `calc()` result to the page on some conditions (like after your $ajax call is success). You need to make an additional $ajax request to another PHP script which one will call `calc()` function and output the results.

So you need to split things to JavaScript part and PHP part like this:

```js
function getResultOfCalc(callback){
    $.ajax({
            url: "calc_php_script.php"
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(data) {
                        //send received data to callback function
                        callback(data);
            },
    });
}

//Next your code
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: ...,
            success: function(data) {
                getResultOfCalc(function(calcResult){
                    //here you get your calc data after your initial ajax is success
                    console.log(calcResult);
                });
            },
            error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {
            console.log('Error' + errorMessage);
            }
});
```

And then your php script must be named calc_php_script.php

```php
echo calc();
```

Depending on what calc() outputs you may want to encode calc() result as JSON:

```php
echo json_encode(calc());
```

Comment: I see know. Thank you for your answer. Really appreciated.